# Jasper server adhoc: too many decimal places

Tags: formatting, jasperserver, decimal-point

I created an Adhoc View in Jasper Studio.
To set decimal places I: right-click > Change Data Format > Select [-1,234.560].

[image]

But the numbers are showing anywhere from 2 to 10 decimal places.
[image]
In the domain / database these fields are floats, and I set Data Properties > Data Format at the domain level to [-1,234.560].
[image]
This is happening with fields that are calculated at the domain level, as well as float values that are pulled straight from the database to the domain.

Any ideas what is happening here?